# Why is this C# code crashing the process?

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var intValue = "test";
                var test = Convert.ToInt32(intValue);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("format exception");
                throw;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("finally");
            }
        }
```

According to me, during conversion from string to int, a FormatException is thrown. Now inside the catch block, we are re throwing the original exception. Why is this not caught in the generic exception catch block? If I put try/catch around the throw then application doesn't crashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is this not caught in the generic exception catch block?

Because the generic exception block catches exceptions that are thrown only within the `try` block and doesn't catch exceptions thrown from `catch` blocks.

So if you intend to throw an exception from the `catch` block and you want to handle it, you will need to wrap the calling code in yet another try/catch.